# XPath 1.0 : Searching over all the elements with contains

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt-1.0

I have an XML document with the following structure :

```
<books>
  <book>
    <title/>
    <author></author>
    ...
  </book>
</books>
```

Now I would like to find all `book`s of an author. I use the following XPath 1.0 expression :

```
/books/book[contains(author,$value)]
```

But this will only returns me all the books where author is on first place (first author-element of a book-element).

How can I achieve it to find also the books where the author is not on first place?
I'm using XSLT 1.0 in Firefox.

Comment: You've asked 7 questions in 7 years and never accepted even a single answer.  Why is that?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please provide a reproducible example of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This XPath,

```
/books/book[author[contains(.,$value)]]
```

will select all `book` elements with an `author` child element whose string value ***contains the substring***, `$value`.

---

This XPath,

```
/books/book[author = $value]
```

will select all `book` elements with an `author` child element whose string value ***is*** `$value`.

Answer (score 0):

In XSLT-1.0 you cannot use a variable in a template matching expression.
It just doesn't work, so either hard-code the value or put it in an `xsl:if` or `xsl:choose`.

So

```
<xsl:template match="/books/book">
    <xsl:if test="contains(author/text(),$value)">
        CONDITION Fulfilled!
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

does work, but using it as a predicate

```
<xsl:template match="/books/book[contains(author/text(),$value)]">
  CONDITION won't work!
</xsl:template>
```

would not, unless you hard-code the matching VALUE like

```
<xsl:template match="/books/book[contains(author/text(),'VALUE')]">
  CONDITION won't work!
</xsl:template>
```